# Realm Database insert data make myapp stopped

Tags: java, android, database, realm

I am trying to figure out how to fix an error with a legacy android project that I have ported over to android studio. I'm hoping this is more an issue with my build.gradle scripts. The class library works properly when coding, complete with completion and such.

I've tried closing android studio, running gradlew clean, then reopening it in android studio and that didn't work.

i have Car.class and it's extends RealmObject
setter and getter methods it's there too

my gradle app :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.ndprwork.cartest"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
```

my Add Class:

```
package com.ndprwork.cartest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import io.realm.Realm;
import io.realm.RealmConfiguration;

public class Add extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);

    final  EditText et_car=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ETcar);
    final  EditText et_mat=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ETmat);
    final  EditText et_model=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ETmodel);
    final  CheckBox cb_new=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.CBnew);

    Button addnew=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bt_addnew);

    addnew.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        Car car=new Car();
            car.setName(et_car.getText().toString());
            car.setMatr(et_mat.getText().toString());
            car.setModel(et_model.getText().toString());
            car.setStat(cb_new.isChecked());

            RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext()).build();
            Realm crealm =Realm.getInstance(config);
            crealm.beginTransaction();
            crealm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(car);
            crealm.commitTransaction();
            Toast.makeText(Add.this,"Done car added",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
    }
    );
   }
  }
```

LOGINPAGE CLASS:

```
package com.ndprwork.cartest;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Loginpage extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_loginpage);

Button addnew=(Button)findViewById(R.id.newadd);
addnew.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        Intent in=new Intent(Loginpage.this,Add.class);
        startActivity(in);


    }
});
}
```

my Log:

```
07-12 16:05:00.537 18135-18135/com.ndprwork.cartest E/dalvikvm: Could  not find class 'android.util.ArrayMap', referenced from method  com.android.tools.fd.runtime.MonkeyPatcher.pruneResourceCache
07-12 16:05:00.557 18135-18135/com.ndprwork.cartest E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.ndprwork.cartest.Loginpage.access$super
07-12 16:05:00.557 18135-18135/com.ndprwork.cartest E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.ndprwork.cartest.Loginpage.access$super
07-12 16:05:00.557 18135-18135/com.ndprwork.cartest E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.media.session.MediaController', referenced from method com.ndprwork.cartest.Loginpage.access$super
07-12 16:05:00.557 18135-18135/com.ndprwork.cartest E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.widget.Toolbar', referenced from method com.ndprwork.cartest.Loginpage.access$super
07-12 16:05:00.577 18135-18135/com.ndprwork.cartest E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.ActivityManager$TaskDescription', referenced from method com.ndprwork.cartest.Loginpage.access$super
07-12 16:05:00.577 18135-18135/com.ndprwork.cartest E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.SharedElementCallback', referenced from method com.ndprwork.cartest.Loginpage.access$super
07-12 16:05:00.577 18135-18135/com.ndprwork.cartest E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.ndprwork.cartest.Loginpage.access$super
07-12 16:05:00.587 18135-18135/com.ndprwork.cartest E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.transition.TransitionManager', referenced from method com.ndprwork.cartest.Loginpage.access$super
07-12 16:05:00.597 18135-18135/com.ndprwork.cartest E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.SharedElementCallback', referenced from method com.ndprwork.cartest.Loginpage.access$super
07-12 16:05:00.607 18135-18135/com.ndprwork.cartest E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.assist.AssistContent', referenced from method com.ndprwork.cartest.Loginpage.access$super
07-12 16:05:00.617 18135-18135/com.ndprwork.cartest E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.SearchEvent', referenced from method com.ndprwork.cartest.Loginpage.access$super
07-12 16:05:00.617 18135-18135/com.ndprwork.cartest E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.ndprwork.cartest.Loginpage.access$super
07-12 16:05:00.807 18135-18135/com.ndprwork.cartest E/ION: ION_IOC_CUSTOM_GET_CONFIG ioctl Failed. Use default
```

what's going on ?
did i make mistakes?

Comment: As the Log says, the problem in in LoginPage. Post the code of that class

Comment: i posted loginpage.class can you tell me what the wrong ?

Comment: Doesn't look like realm has anything to do with it

Comment: Intent in = new Intent(this, Add.class);
Try with this, without the Loginpage.this, only this